# Приватные свойства в js

Tags: javascript

Я не знаю как правильно сказать, но как сделать свойство, которое было бы не видно внешне, но было бы видно методам установленных через прототип? Вот типа -

```
var Class = function(){
    var _array = []; // приватное или протектед свойство
};

Class.prototype.method = function(){
    // как обратиться здесь к _array?
};
```

Возможно такое сделать из коробки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Средства языка такого, насколько я знаю, не предоставляют. Поэтому javascript-еры договорились, что все свойства которые начинаются со знака нижнего подчеркивания '_' являются приватными. В вашем случае:

```
var Class = function(){
    this._array = []; // приватное или протектед свойство
};

Class.prototype.method = function(){
    // как обратиться здесь к _array?
    this._array

};

var instance = new Class();

instance._array.push('string') // но мы то знаем, что так делать нельзя
```

**Update**

Появилась идея. Шифровать имя свойства и делать его enumerable. Костыль:

```
var prive = function (that, propName, newValue) {
  var decodeStr = function (str) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(
      str,
      function (char, i) {
        return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)-5)
      }).join('');
  },
  decodedPropName = decodeStr(propName);
  if (arguments.length >= 3) {
    // set private property
    Object.defineProperty(that, decodedPropName, {
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      value: newValue,
    });
  } else {
    //get private property
    return that[decodedPropName];
  }
}
```

[Демонстрация](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/3b4sdgtu/3/)

Comment: @alvoro, Спасибо! Чем больше я углубляюсь в js, тем больше мне кажется, что его переоценили. Я начал его постигать из создания игр, и мне говорили, что он в десять раз быстрее as3. А на деле оказалось, что игры нормальные, только у говорящих в воображении и инструментов, по сравнению с as3, можно сказать что и нет. Да и мне кажется, что он подходит для далеких от ООП верстальщиков, а вот если игроделы в него влезут, то они ужаснуться от отсутствия ООП. А начав его делать, вся скорость сойдет на нет. Сомнительное в общем "превосходство". Не убийца он флеша.. Убийца флеша - наивность.

Comment: > ужаснуться от отсутствия ООП

Ну это вы громко сказали. В javascript [все есть](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) для этого вашего ооп)) Выглядит не так, как в других языках, но все же есть.

Comment: Оно то есть, но очень похоже на детское чаепитие.))

Comment: Я даже не понимаю, нужно ли для публик свойств делать геттеры-сеттеры или в js они не нужны)

Comment: > нужно ли для публик свойств делать геттеры-сеттеры 

Если нужно, то нужно, а если не нужно - то не нужно))) А если серьезно, то почитайте теорию по javascript, немного попрактикуйтесь и все станет на свои места.

Comment: @vas Я бы на вашем месте не делал таких громких заявлений, критиковать язык можно только тогда, когда его хорошо знаешь и умеешь пользоваться.

Comment: @vas, соглашусь с предыдущим комментарием. Более того, программировать на js надо абстрагировавшись от типичного ООП и перестать думать стилем других ООП языков и не пытаться js подравнять под них, тогда ваш ждет успех

Comment: @alvoro я глобально не договаривался ни с кем насчет "приватных свойств с `_`" это костыль и он не нужен обычно. в es6 вроде будут приватные свойства, но не реализовано ещё нигде.

Comment: @eicto, ок. Возможно я сильно громко заявил по поводу договоренности. Но в свою защиту смею заметить, что вот [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties) рекомендация использовать префиксы идет на первом месте.

Comment: @Lookingfor СПЕРВАДОБЕЙСЯ

Comment: @Etki вы путаете спервадобейся с дилетанством. действительно @vas не прав.

Comment: Я и признаю, что неправ! Язык объектный и этого больше чем достаточно. Но странный он и все! Хотя меня устраивает. В любом языке есть чувство "чего-то не хватает", но в js у меня чувство, что нехватает совсем уж чего-то простого.

Comment: @eicto ничего я не путаю. Я бы сказал, что даже наоборот, чем больше варишься в языке, тем меньше замечаешь его недостатки.

Comment: @Etki СПЕРВАДОБЕЙСЯ, это если бы на мнение @vas сказали бы - сделай лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Оберните класс в анонимную функцию, воспользовавшись ограниченной областью видимости для приватных свойств.

```
(function(){
   var private_method = function(){}; // приватный метод не будет виден снаружи
   var private_property = 'ololo'; // приватное свойство

   var Class = function(){};

   Class.prototype.public_method = function(){ // паблик метод
      var x = private_method(private_property); 
      // приватные свойства и методы можно использовать здесь
   };

   window.Class = Class; // выносим класс в общую область видимости
})();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vldmir/v2tfj6ey/)

Comment: и каждый инстанс Class будет иметь одинаковые приватные property :)
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/v2tfj6ey/1/

Answer (score 4):

Я этот вопрос решал вот так:

```
(function (exports) {
    /*
     * sample prototype,
     *
     * inherit @boolean if true - return privates object,
     *
     */
    function A(inherit) {
        var privates = { //setup private vars, they could be also changed, added in method or children
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3
        };
        //setup public methods which uses privates
        this.aPlus = bindPlus("aPlus", this, privates); //pass method name as string!
        this.aGet = bindPlus("aGet", this, privates);
        if (inherit) {
            return privates;
        }
    }
    A.prototype.aPlus = function () {
        var args = getArgs(arguments),
            //self is "this" here (applied/called too), object reference is still this        
            privates = args.shift(),
            self = args.shift(),
            //function real arguments            
            n = args.shift();
        return privates.a += n;
    };

    A.prototype.aGet = function (n) {
        var args = getArgs(arguments),                
            privates = args.shift(),
            self = args.shift();        
        console.error(this, self,privates);
        return privates.a;
    };

    exports.A = A;
    exports.getArgs = getArgs; //should be hidden somehow, but this is out of the story
    exports.bindPlus = bindPlus;

    //utilites
    function getArgs(arg) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arg);
    }
    //вот здесь в общем-то ядро идеи
    function bindPlus(funct, self, privates) {
        /**
        * if uncomment here and comment same line later,
        * it will be run faster, but it would be impossible 
        * to change prototype after constructor run (tests after ----- could be incorrect)
        */

        //var func=Object.getPrototypeOf(self)[funct].bind(self, privates);
        return function () {                        
            var func=Object.getPrototypeOf(self)[funct].bind(self, privates);
            var args=getArgs(arguments); //this could be changed to speedup, but need to change method itself
                args.unshift(this); //called/applied this
            return func.apply(null, args);
        };
    }
})(this);

//inherited 
function B(inherit) {
    var privates = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.call(this, true);
    privates.d = 4;
    this.dGet = bindPlus("dGet", this, privates);
    if (inherit) {
        return privates;
    }
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.constructor = B;

B.prototype.aGet = function () {
    var args = getArgs(arguments);
        var privates = args.shift(),
        self = args.shift();
    console.warn("B.aGet",self, privates);
    return privates.a;
};

B.prototype.dGet = function () {
    var args = getArgs(arguments),
        privates = args.shift();
        self = args.shift(),
    console.warn("B.dGet", self, privates);
    return privates.d;
};
```

но это немного тормозно и неудобно, лучшего способа не нашел, чтобы работало.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/TJH9Q/

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз тут уже толпа, внесу лепту, так сказать. Вкратце - из глобальной области видимости исключается один объект `_this`, который и содержит все приватные поля-методы. Плюсы - прозрачность и вроде даже удобство.

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var _this = {}; // private container

    _this.private1 = 0; // private var 1
    _this.private2 = 1; // private var 2

    _this.incPrivate = function() { // private function
      _this.private1++;
      _this.private2++;
    };

    this.public1 = 2; // public var 1
    this.public2 = 3; // public var 2 
    this.logPrivate = function() { // public function
      console.log(_this);
      return this;
    };
    this.incPublic = function() { // public function
      this.public1++;
      this.public2++;
      return this;
    };
    this.proxyIncPrivate = function() { // public function / proxy
      _this.incPrivate();
      return this;
    };
    this.logPublic = function() { // public function
      console.log(this);
      return this;
    };
}

var MyInstance = new MyClass();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frffsnm2/3/)

**UPDADE**

Заморочился я тут и сделал реализацию для основных типов свойств в JS. не в курсе, что там с памятью, но по работе оно стало похоже на нормальные языки :)

```
(function() {
    var _class = {
        // доступно в объекте и прототипе,
        // один экземпляр (изменяется отовсюду)
        // недоступно из глобальной области видимости
        privateStatic1: 0,
        privateStatic2: 1,
        privateStaticMethod: function() {
            console.log('called private static method');
        }
    }
    var MyClass = function() {
        var _this = {
            // доступно только из методов объекта,
            // изменяется только объект
            // недоступно из глобала и класса
            private1: 2,
            private2: 3,
            privateMethod: function() {
              console.log('called private method');
            }
        };
        // доступно отовсюду после создания объекта,
        // изменяется только объект
        // недоступно из глобала и класса
        this.public1 = 4;
        this.public2 = 5;
        this.publicMethod = function() {
          console.log('called public method');
        };
    };
    // доступно отовсюду,
    // один экземпляр

    // дублирование для возможности вызова через MyClass без создания объекта
    MyClass.prototype.publicStatic1 = 6;
        MyClass.publicStatic1 = MyClass.prototype.publicStatic1;
    MyClass.prototype.publicStatic2 = 7;
        MyClass.prototype.publicStatic2 = MyClass.prototype.publicStatic2;
    MyClass.prototype.publicStaticMethod = function() {
      console.log('called public static method');
    }
    MyClass.publicStaticMethod = MyClass.prototype.publicStaticMethod;
    window.MyClass = MyClass;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux95ub87/1/ + консольный вывод результатов всех вызовов.

Comment: В такой реализации нет возможности использовать "приватные" свойства в прототипе, ваши методы для каждого инстанса будут сидеть в памяти

Comment: @likerRr , ну, я не претендую на универсальность, вообще сложно без громоздкостей что-то предложить.

Тем более, использование `private` из области, по сути, `public static` (php `MyClass::method` и в нем `$this->private1` ) работать и не должно.

Если же говорить о `private static`, то в ответе @vldmir как раз это и реализовано. Можно скомбинировать.

Comment: Чем я, собственно, и занялся. Наплевал на прототипы, правда, зато реализовал "как надо" public (+static), private (+static). Прототип этот вообще черт-те что, если честно. Обновляю ответ.

Comment: @Sh4dow, Вы не щадите ресурсы пользователя :)

Answer (score 0):

Приватные поля могут появиться в ближайшем будущем.
Они уже поддерживаются многими браузерами (`Chrome 72`, `Firefox 69`), а так же `node.js 12`. 
[Добавлены](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/#ecmascript-private-fields) в `TypeScript 3.8`.

Примерный синтаксис такой:

```js
class Point {
  #x;
  #y;
  
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.#x = x;
    this.#y = y;
  }
  
  equals(point) {
    return this.#x === point.#x && this.#y === point.#y;
  }
}

const point1 = new Point(10, 10);
const point2 = new Point(10, 10);

console.log(point1.x);
console.log(point2.equals(point1))
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields)