# Регулярное выражение для внутренних ссылок (только указанного домена)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где указать нужный домен в Regexp (.NET), чтобы парсил только нужные (внутренние) линки указанного домена (фильтр по домену)?

Интересует пример на данной регулярке:

> (http|https):\/\/[\w-*]+(.[\w-*]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&amp;/~+#])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без объяснений:

**[Посмотреть пример](http://regex101.com/r/zT5fS9/1)**

```
(http|https):\/\/hashcode.ru([\w-.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&amp;\/~+#])?

# http://hashcode.com.ru/questions/354535/
# https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354535/ - выбрана эта
# http://google.ru/questions/354535/
```

С наглядной группировкой основных частей:

**[Посмотреть пример](http://regex101.com/r/rF5eA7/2)**

```
(?P<scheme>http|https):\/\/(?P<host>(?P<domain>[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)\.(?P<zone>[\w-]+))(?P<request_uri>[\w-.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&amp;\/~+#])?
```

---

```
# http://hashcode.com.ru/questions/354535/

# scheme        [0-4]   `http`
# host          [7-22]  `hashcode.com.ru`
# domain        [7-19]  `hashcode.com`
# zone          [19-22] `ru`
# request_uri   [22-40] `/questions/354535/`
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем так сложно? Если у вас есть строка с адресом, применяйте `new Uri(str).IsAbsoluteUri`.

Если вы собираетесь распарсить HTML регулярками, просто не делайте этого.

В любом случае **никогда не пишите парсер на регулярках**, пользуйтесь готовыми парсерами.

Comment: интересует пример именно на основе моей регулярки к сожалению,а на счет: new Uri(str).IsAbsoluteUri. не знаком, так же буду рад примерам...

Comment: Сорри за археологию, столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Помогла вот эта статья: http://2lx.ru/2009/02/parsing-urlov-v-c/

Comment: @z668: Спасибо, не знал.